# using rdmsr to check IA32_MCi_STATUS for bit 43 (IERR)

Tags: intel, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, msr

I'm trying to understand how to pull MSR and MCA data using rdmsr, and I can't quite get it to work how I expect it to work.

Basically, I want to use rdmsr to check IA32_MCi_STATUS to see if bit 43 is tripped (IERR on my CPU), but instead of getting a large hex output to convert to binary, I'm getting a small hex number (1f or ff), which definitely doesn't seem right at all.

I'm running this:

rdmsr -a IA32_MCi_STATUS

which is giving me a single result for each core, but it's always either 1f or ff (which can't be right as this register has lots of bit data associated with it)

Have I gone potato?  What am I doing wrong? OS is CentOS.

Comment: What is IERR? I cannot find it in the IS32_MCi_STATUS (bit 43 is part of a counter). Also, 1f or ff don't seem valid error codes at first sight.

Comment: I'm using IA32_MCi_STATUS, not IS32_MCi_STATUS.  IERR is an internal error (usually preceeds CATERR [Catastrophic Error]).  And yes I agree, those error codes seem wrong to me as well, so I assume I'm doing something wrong.  I'm using the Intel Software Developers Manual, info I'm trying to use is under Volume 3B, page 16-5

Comment: I also meant IA32_MCi_STATUS :) That was a typo. The IERR is a pin, not a bit (see section 8.7.5 of Volume 3).

Comment: ah, I see.... so how would one use rdmsr to see if IERR has been exerted?